# Maven compilation with Java

Tags: java, maven, version

I tried to execute .jar file, however it seems like my java project didn't compiled with java version 7 or higher.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project blahblah: Compilation failure 
[ERROR] blahblah.java:[73,38] multi-catch statement is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable multi-catch statement)
```

However, my java version is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

And my maven version is

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T20:57:37+09:00)
Maven home: /Users/sundong/Downloads/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: ko_KR, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.10.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?
(I don't want to change my code to -source 1.5 compatible version again)

Comment: See [setting the -source and -target for Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

Comment: somewhere in pom file you have `maven-compiler-plugin` plugin configured to use wrong java version